# Is it bad to use the plus character ( '+') in filenames for a library?

Tags: c++, static-libraries, filenames

I'm wondering what you guys think of using the + character in folders and filenames for a library I'm working on. Let's say my lib is called lib++, should I name my files and folders using "lib++" or I should stick to something safer like "libpp" (plus plus) or "libxx".

UnitTest++ uses the + character in its filenames.

Comment: Are you talking about C++ libraries? For .net libraries it's certainly bad practice.

Comment: Yes, C++. Why is it bad practice in C#?

Comment: The name of a .net assembly typically corresponds to the namespace, and namespaces containing a `+` don't work in most .net languages, including C#.

Comment: Wish I could -1 your comment for assuming .NET===C#. But I can't, and that also means you can't -1 this comment, so it balances out ;)

Comment: Surely you can think of a better library name than "lib++"?

Answer (score 5):

If you intend your library to be widely portable to other (particularly, older) operating systems, then I'd avoid the "+", and stick with A-Z,a-z,0-9,_

Two issues to consider:-

- Does the operating system itself allow the character? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename#Comparison_of_filename_limitations
- Does the language allow the character in imported (for C++, included) filenames?

For example, for a C++ library: Your OS should be able to have files called `lib++.h` and `lib++.lib` on disk OK - but you would have to deviate from standard practice for header guard naming...

```
in lib++.h:-

#ifndef LIB++_H
#define LIB++_H

...
#endif
```

That's going to end in tears, I think...

*(Actually, the more I think about it, the more potential points of failure there are: Your version control software, your IDE, your documentation generator, in fact pretty much ANY tool you use that looks at filenames. Now, you may be lucky and none of this causes any problem for you or anyone else who ever tries to use your library, but that's just not the way I'd want to bet. )*

Comment: If you're going to invoke the "standard practice" argument, let's talk about _libstdc++_.

Comment: hmm. Fair point... but I guess the "++" doesn't actually exist in any of the filenames #included, because the libstdc++ directory must be in the search path? I think there's a distinction between 'library names' and 'file names'?

Comment: I certainly don't see a reason to assume that file names must match library names one-to-one in all cases. e.g. it's not `libBoost-...`

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - Indeed - but the question is about + in _filenames_. I don't have libstdc++ to look at, but do any of its filenames actually contain "++"?